# creating engraved border using css

Tags: css, border

Is there any trick to create engraved border using CSS on this color #505050 ? I have been searching on web since hours but could not find any CSS solution. Although, I could have made on photoshop but i am not good at it.

Comment: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/cssborders.html

Comment: @AkhilThesiya well, i know how to create borders but don't know to create engraved borders :D

Comment: As Natrium says, `border-style:groove` is a way to get an engraved style, you don't get much control over the rendering of it. Can you show us a quick mockup of the look you want?

Comment: http://tutobx.tumblr.com/post/24806696944/raised-and-pressed-div-using-css

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly the look you're after but Mozilla has some fantastic documentation on the `border-style` CSS rule. The following styles are available:

- none
- hidden
- dotted
- dashed
- solid
- double
- groove
- ridge
- inset
- outset

Image examples and more explanation is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style).

Comment: I guess the OP wants `groove`

Comment: @Natrium `groove` one helped me.